# html code for Google Maps directions not working

Tags: html, css, api, google-maps

I'm trying to allow the user to enter 2 cities, using google's Autofill, and then draw the line between them on Google Maps. The autofill works fine for both boxes. The starting location works ( when the user enters a city, the map zooms in to that city and the marker appears ), but nothing happens when the end location is entered. If anyone see's what the problem in, I would greatly appreciate some advice.

***Directions.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Places Autocomplete</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

<style>
  body 
    {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
  #lred { color: #FF0000;}
  #map-canvas 
    {
        height: 400px;
        width: 600px;
        margin-top: 0.6em;
    }
  start {border: 1px solid  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
  start.notfound 
    {
        background-color: #F5A9A9;
        }
  end {border: 1px solid  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
  end.notfound 
    {
        background-color: #F5A9A9;
        }
 </style>

 <script>
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  function initialize() 
    {
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var mapOptions = 
            {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var options = 
            {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
            };
        var start = document.getElementById('start');   
        var sAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(start, options);
        var end = document.getElementById('end');   
        var eAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(end, options);

        sAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
        eAutocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });

        google.maps.event.addListener(sAutocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
            start.className = '';
            var place = sAutocomplete.getPlace();
                // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
                if (!place.geometry) 
                    { 
                        start.className = 'notfound';
                        return;
                    }
                else 
                    {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(6);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                    }
            var image = 
                {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
                };
            marker.setIcon(image);
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
     });
    }

    function calcRoute() {
    var start2 = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end2 = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin:start2,
        destination:end2,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
   }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
 <div>
  <input id="start" onchange="calcRoute();" type="text" size="50">
  <input id="end" onchange="calcRoute();" type="text" size="50">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Load your HTML file in a syntax checking editor such as [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). It identified the errors in these two lines:

```
<input id="start" onchange="calcRoute(); type="text" size="50">
<input id="end" onchange="calcRoute(); type="text" size="50">
```

Do you see it? There are missing quote marks in both tags.

After that is fixed, your page behaves differently. Now it does call the `calcRoute()` function, which wasn't getting called at all before. But there is an error shown in the JavaScript console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: directionsService is not defined
```

And sure enough, I don't see `directionsService` defined anywhere in the code.

Over to you...

Comment: Thanks. Those were all clear errors on my part. I think it's time to use a syntax editor haha. but even after fixing all those mistakes, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried your latest code from the updated question and it works fine. The keyboard interface isn't quite 100% yet, but if I select an autocomplete entry with the mouse it works great. You could fix the keyboard interaction any of several ways, for example by putting the input fields inside a form with a submit button, and handle the form submit in JavaScript (call `calcRoute` and suppress the default form action).

Comment: Wait so when you run my code, it connects the 2 points? The autocmplete was previously working, its just the directions part was not.

Comment: Yup, as long as I use the mouse to select from each autocomplete list, it works in Chrome at least. Didn't try other browsers. Update: just tried Firefox, works fine there too.

Comment: hmm thats weird. it simply does not work when i run it on safari.

Comment: Add this line of code inside `calcRoute()`, right after the two lines that assign `start2` and `end2`: `console.log( start2, ' : ', end2 );`. Now try it in Safari with the console open.

Comment: I was able to fix that by wrapping `calcRoute()` in a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 250ms.